# How can I fix "Failed Storing private key?" Error01 problem?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I also saw the same problem when I entered command "./byfn.sh -m generate". Someone told me it's permission problem, but I don't know at all becuase this is my first studying hyperledger fabric. I need more friendly help! Thank you in advance!

```html
hyper@traveler5260-VirtualBox:~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network$ ../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
org1.example.com
2019-08-12 00:45:18.288 KST [bccsp_sw] storePrivateKey -> ERRO 001 Failed storing private key [000c5c07b91bf1bf3a8aee1b30591ee5af15844ecbcf3108a58a37ae9db0aa70]: [open crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/000c5c07b91bf1bf3a8aee1b30591ee5af15844ecbcf3108a58a37ae9db0aa70_sk: permission denied]
Error generating signCA for org org1.example.com:
Failed storing key [ECDSAP256]: Failed storing ECDSA private key [open crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/000c5c07b91bf1bf3a8aee1b30591ee5af15844ecbcf3108a58a37ae9db0aa70_sk: permission denied]
```

Comment: you should give chmod 777 to this path crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ . This will avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should give `chmod 777` to this path `crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/` . This will avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'll try!